# The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match. (Input is bitmap)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

```kotlin
private fun uploadImage() {
        val model = ConvertedModel.newInstance(this)
        lateinit var reducedBitmap: Bitmap

        if (outwear1 != null) {
            reducedBitmap = reduceBitmapImage(outwear1!!)
            binding.ivOut2.setImageBitmap(reducedBitmap)
            val resized: Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(reducedBitmap, 224, 224, true)
            Log.d("Resized", "Width: ${resized.width}, Height: ${resized.height}")
            val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 224, 224, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
            Log.d("TensorBuffer", "Shape: ${inputFeature0.shape.contentToString()}, Size: ${inputFeature0.flatSize}")
            var tbuffer = TensorImage.fromBitmap(resized)
            var byteBuffer = tbuffer.buffer

            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

            val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
            val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

            Log.d("OutputTF", outputFeature0.toString())
            model.close()
        }
    }
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7B3f.png)

I try to use a bitmap as an input for my TensorflowLite, the problem is somewhere in the buffer size I think because it is not optimized?

Comment: did you check the input size of the tflite model ?